# Finding Carmichael Numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I cant seem to figure out why my python code is telling me wrong carmichael numbers. Thanks in advance. I just cant see the error in the algorithm.

```
def isCarmichaelNumber( x ):
    for y in range(2,x):
        #check if prime
        if math.gcd (x, y) == 1:
            if pow(y, x-1, x) != 1:
                return False
    return True

print(isCarmichaelNumber(1847))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking to see whether `x` is prime.  By definition, a Carmichael number must be composite.  For any prime `x`, `pow(y, x-1, x) == 1` for all `y` in `range(2, x)`, so will *incorrectly* return `True`.  1847 is prime, which is why your function claims it's a Carmichael number.

One way to fix it:

```
def isCarmichaelNumber(x):
    import math
    isprime = True
    for y in range(2,x):
        if math.gcd(x, y) == 1:
            if pow(y, x-1, x) != 1:
                return False
        else:
            isprime = False
    return not isprime
```